# ESLint - Override rules from eslint-plugin-prettier

Tags: eslint, prettier

I am using ESLint with the prettier [plugin](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) and [configuration](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/):

```js
// eslintrc.js
extends: [
  `eslint:recommended`,
  `plugin:react/recommended`,
  `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended`,
  `plugin:prettier/recommended`,
  `prettier/react`,
  `prettier/@typescript-eslint`
]
```

This works great, but I would like to disable a certain prettier rule, which is removing "unneeded" parentheses (removing them actually breaks my code):

```js
// Replace `(state.counter)` with `state.counter` eslint(prettier/prettier)
return <div>{(state.counter)}</div>
```

As you can see from the message above, it doesn't state which rule exactly is causing this behavior and therefore I don't know which one to override.

I have tried to override all rules found in [eslint-prettier-config](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/master/index.js), but nothing worked and I don't want to keep using `// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not currently possible to disable that specific rule from *prettier* through configuration, but to override rules in *eslint* that come from the `extends` block, you can either write in the rule like this:

```js
"rules": {
  "prettier/prettier": "off"
  "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [
    "error",
    { "functions": false, "variables": true, "classes": true },
  ],
}
```

Or to only override it for a specific file pattern you can override it in the `overrides` block.

```js
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*.html"],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": "off"
    }
  }
]
```

Here I am showing both the config you were looking for, and an inherited rule from a nested package to show future visitors how to do it.

Comment: In the `overrides` section, how did you know you should put `"prettier/prettier"`? Why not just `prettier`, is this documented anywhere? I'm trying to do the same for the cypress plugin and don't know what exactly to put

Comment: @TobiasFeil If you are using VSCode, the source of lint errors are usually shown in the problem output, it says `prettier/prettier` instead of `prettier`, that's probably where they got it.

Answer (score 22):

Prettier is not so configurable. You can try configuration they have: https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Put `.prettierrc` file, or eslint config like this:

```
{
  rules: {
   'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        trailingComma: 'all',
        tabWidth: 2,
        semi: false,
        singleQuote: true,
        bracketSpacing: true,
        eslintIntegration: true,
        printWidth: 120,
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, saved me a lot of time <3